# Error running app. I tried to run the Android app emulator but it stays at "Launching on devices"

Tags: android, android-emulator, runtime-error

I'm working in Android Studio with a phone emulator  (Pixel 4 API 28).

When I finished coding the app, in Kotlin, I pressed the play button and first it ran "Starting AVD", then it get to "Launching on devices" and stays there for a while. Finally, the run crashed and a red sign appeared saying "Error running 'app'. The application could not be installed." and another that says "Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed.

Please, help me to solve this, to run my emulator.

I can't find some information about it.